# How do I change when a Silverlight DataGrid updates bound data?

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

Currently my `DataGrid`(Silverlight 4) is updating when I step off of a cell.  I need it to update whenever the value of a cell is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came to my own answer and its similar to the behavior injection used to instantly change a TextBox's binding source ([see here](http://zoltanarvai.com/2009/07/22/binding-update-on-textbox-textchanged-event-using-behaviors/)). I subclassed `DataGrid` and added the following code:

```
    protected override void OnPreparingCellForEdit(DataGridPreparingCellForEditEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreparingCellForEdit(e);

        TextBox textBox = e.EditingElement as TextBox;
        if (textBox != null)
        {
            textBox.TextChanged -= OnTextChanged;
            textBox.TextChanged += OnTextChanged;
        }

        ComboBox comboBox = e.EditingElement as ComboBox;
        if (comboBox != null)
        {
            comboBox.SelectionChanged -= OnSelectionChanged;
            comboBox.SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChanged;
        }
    }

    private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox comboBox = sender as ComboBox;

        if (comboBox == null)
            return;

        BindingExpression expression = comboBox.GetBindingExpression(ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty);
        if (expression != null)
            expression.UpdateSource();

        expression = comboBox.GetBindingExpression(ComboBox.SelectedItemProperty);
        if (expression != null)
            expression.UpdateSource();
    }

    private void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;

        if (textBox == null)
            return;

        BindingExpression expression = textBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);

        if (expression == null)
            return;

        expression.UpdateSource();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

just implement INotifyPropertyChanged on class which you set  itemssource of datagrid.

for example

```
 public class CustomType:INotifyPropertyChanged
 {

 }

 List<CustomType> list=new List<CustomType>();
```

add items

```
datagrid.ItemsSource=list;
```

Binding Mode=TwoWay

Comment: That doesn't answer my question at all.  I already am using `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  I need the change to happen in the opposite direction when the grid is changed, the object should be changed as well. Instantly, without having to step off of the cell.

Comment: what  about  if binding mode to set TwoWay

Comment: {Binding Path=PropertyName,Mode=TwoWay}

Comment: It is. The problem is not binding.  Its a problem of the control not changing the data until I step off of it.

Comment: please can you more explain your  example